# comm command with awk (or sed)

Tags: shell, awk, sed, conemu

I'd like to print out all lines that only exist in one of the two input streams using `comm` (the use of this command is not mandatory though). However using `awk` or `sed` seems to mess up it a bit. Eg. `comm -23 (git branch -r | awk -F\"[/]\" '/matchinstring/{print $2}' | sort) (blah blah other stream)` fails ("The system cannot find the file specified."). `awk` tries to use the `| sort...` part. Is there a way to overcome this? Sure, I could output to 2 files, and than use `comm` on those two files, but can I make it a one-liner? I'm using ConEmu.

Example input 1:

```
matchingstring-234
matchingstring-456
```

Example input 2:

```
matchingstring-123
matchingstring-345
matchingstring-456
```

Expected output:

```
matchingstring-234
```

Comment: Please post sample Input_file(s) and expected output file(s) too in code tags in your post. So that we could help you on same.

Comment: The point is there are no input our output files. git will generate a string stream. Also (blah blah other stream) is also a string stream generated by git. But I edit my post with how those stream look like,

Comment: Gotcha, but if you could show what is the output of your very first command and what is expected output, it will be easier for us to help here.

Comment: The question is not related to ConEmu, but only the shell you are using!

Answer (score 2):

Input files:

```
$ cat f1
matchingstring-234
matchingstring-456

$ cat f2
matchingstring-123
matchingstring-345
matchingstring-456
```

**Using awk**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1];next}!( $1 in arr)' f2 f1
matchingstring-234
```

**Using grep**

```
$ grep -v -F -x -f f2 f1
matchingstring-234
```

**Using join**

```
$ join -v 2 <(sort f2) <(sort f1)
matchingstring-234
```

> From Man `grep`

```
-v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

-F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular
          expressions), separated by newlines,  any  of  which  is  to  be
          matched.

-x, --line-regexp
          Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the whole line.
          For a regular expression pattern, this  is  like  parenthesizing
          the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.

-f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty  file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  Multiple
          -f can be used to specify different files.
```

Comment: This would work in most instances, but one note: this will not handle duplicates (that is if you had a file with `a` `a` `b`, and another `a` `b`, this would not detect the extra `a` line.  (The OP quoted `git branch` though, and this would likely not ouptut duplicate lines)

Comment: The question is not about how to get the difference of the two sets (for that the comm -23 is just fine). And as I mentioned I'd like to use the command without files. All of your solutions use files as input.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bash (based on your tags), you could use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
comm -23 <(command1) <(command2)
```

For example:

```
~> comm -23 <(echo a; echo b) <(echo b; echo c)
a
```

Comment: I see, so the shell could be an issue. I have to use a windows version, which in this case is ConEmu-Maximus5. I've tried your suggestion, but apparently conEmu doesn't like it.

Comment: Ahh, yes, this is bash (or zsh) specific.   Since you tagged your question with bash I was assuming you were using that.   You could look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309594 but I'm not sure that's more readable than using files...

Comment: All right, in this case I change the bash tag to conemu.

Comment: ConEmu is not a bash obviously. But you CAN run bash in ConEmu, and ConEmu will not prohibit you to run suggested command in the bash prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer depends on the shell you use.

As @HardcoreHenry and @shellter mentioned for bash and ksh(93) you can use `comm -23 <(command1) <(command2)`.

In windows' PowerShell you could use `comm -23 $(command1) $(command2)` if you had `awk` module (https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/318), which is not built-in by default.

In windows' Cmder (which is the default shell of ConEmu, what I tried to use) this is not possible. You can change the used shell in ConEmu either by typing in `bash <enter>` (obviously this changes the shell to bash). Or clicking "create new shell" (arrow next to the green + sigh in the bottom right corner) > select a shell from the popup. Or menu > Settings > Startup > Specified named task (this sets the shell that ConEmu starts by default).